# Why did the Guardians of the Galaxy trust Xandar to safely store the Orb?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

At the end of Guardians of the Galaxy, the main protagonists decide to store the Orb (containing one of the Infinity Stones) at Xandar with the Nova Corps. However Xandar didn't exactly strike me as a secure location, since it barely managed to resist Ronan's attack and was only saved thanks to the intervention of the Guardians.

What was the logic behind leaving the Stone on Xandar? Is it simply a movie plot to make sure the Orb can be easily stolen in future movies?

Comment: What is the alternative?

Comment: Embed it into a block of lead and dump it in the deepest sea of some random planet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there is logic behind leaving the stone on Xandar. Here are a few thoughts:

- The stone is already there. Choosing another place automatically begs the question of whether it’s worth the effort to move it.
- Moving the stone carries enormous risk. Since the stone is so valuable, stealing the stone while in transit offers numerous opportunities and great reward for thieves.
- There is a fake stone leaving Xandar. Any news that the real stone is in motion would set off a firestorm. Yondu Udonta will think the stone is in motion for monetary purposes, and that will set off a vendetta hunt. That is something that Starlord would want to avoid. Additionally, he would like to see that Yondu continues to think he has the real stone by not opening its container.
- The Nova Corps expressed sincere willingness to safeguard the stone. A poor choice would be to find a more powerful protector that is not actually willing or interested in safeguarding it. Or worse yet, they will turn around and use it for their own purposes.
- What will they do? Safeguard it themselves? They know they cannot pull that off.

Comment: In addition, there's an obvious problem with mistrust; if they don't leave it at Xandar, after the Xandarians have asked to be allowed to safeguard the stone, they're basically saying that 1) the Xandarians are too weak to protect it, 2) they don't trust the Xandarians or 3) they don't like the Xandarians. It would probably be better to give the Xandarians a fake stone and hurl the real one into any random black hole, or, in the lack of a black hole/in case it would destroy the universe, into the a random sun.

Answer (score 7):

While Xandar was not 100% safe from the sneak attack by Ronan, the main danger was Ronan and the Power Stone. If we remove them from the equation, the attack would have hurt many civilians,  but the planet would not have been destroyed. Any country with a standing army is at risk for a painful sneak attack, but it wouldn't destroy the whole country. Here, the Nova corps are a large intergalactic army and have the man power to guard the stone from conventional attacks. The Nova corps and the Kree, which Ronan is, were at war for centuries without annihilating each other, and control large parts of the Galaxy. Ronan ' s attack is an exception to the rule and there is no reason to consider the Nova corps or Xandar as an unsafe place to keep the stone.

Obviously, they will up the security around Xandar now that they are guarding it.